# How read id3 tags from BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, mp3, id3

this link not helped me, but this is id3_1 http://willcode4beer.com/parsing.jsp?set=mp3ID3

There are many libraries, but not one does not work with the stream.

Tell the library, or tell me how much information needs to be downloaded, that would save the file and transfer libraries that work with the File.

Comment: see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147/i-need-an-id3-tag-reader-library-for-java-preferably-a-fast-one

Answer (score 1):

How much needs to be read to obtain the ID3 information depends on the version of ID3 information in the stream. For ID3v1 it will be the last 128 bytes (or last 227+128 bytes for extended ID3v1); for ID3v2 it will be at the beginning.

Comment: If downloading is 128 bytes, stored in a file and send in those functions, then it will work?
unless it finds will need to download the latest 227 and again to send a feature?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, the idea of downloading the beginning of the file (?? bytes for ID3v2 header) and joining it with the last 227+128 bytes and writing that to a file and running the ID3 information extraction on this file should work fine. You'll have to look up how long an ID3v2 header can be at the start of the file.

Comment: ID3v1 - ID3v1: 128 bytes + Extended tag (placed before the ID3v1 tag): 227 bytes. ID3v2 I read but not understand. REad for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3